# Android - Toolbar issue on older version

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app using Android Studio.
The minimum SDK is 14 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH), the target SDK is 23 (M).

The main Activity contains a list and by touching any item, an Intent starts and shows another Activity containing some info.

The detail Activity, on its Toolbar, has the Back button on the left, and the Toolbar title and all other infos are set from DetailsActivity.java depending on the item chosen.

I ran many tests on Android 5.0 and 5.1 and the app is working perfectly.

Now I'm running tests on Android 4.0.2 and 4.1.2, and there is something wrong.
The Back button and title in the detail Toolbar are not shown.

I tried also with 4.3 and 4.4, but my emulator does not start, so I will run other tests when I will find some physical devices.

Here a little piece of code from DetailsActivity.java:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String newTitle="x";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(newTitle);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Here my content_detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.biovita.catalogowhysport.DetailActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#706C6D"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.biovita.catalogowhysport.DetailActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:maxWidth="215dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="productImage"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:minHeight="15dp"
            android:stackFromBottom="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here my activity_detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".DetailActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black_whysport"
        android:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Do you have any idea about what the problem is?

Thanks in advance. :)

UPDATE

Also on Android 4.3 and 4.4 the Back button and the title in the detail Activity are not shown.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: I will check the link, thank you! :)

Comment: @TheTool I don't think the link can help me, I'm developing app for both Android 4 and 5, and I want Material graphics on both systems. I think that only using Appcompat and then Toolbar I could do it.
Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why this was all happening.

My activity_detail.xml was wrong, I edited it in this way and now it is working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```